# testrpc - Number of ethers are too low

Tags: testrpc

I am testing few of my solidity contracts using testrpc. However, testrpc has only a few ethers. Is there any way I can increase this limit ( say 500 ethers in all accounts) .

Answer (score 3):

As documented here:

https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc

--account: Specify `--account=`... (no 's') any number of times passing arbitrary private keys and their associated balances to generate initial addresses:

$ testrpc --account="privatekey,**balance**" [--account="privatekey,balance"]

Hope it helps.